# Laravel keeps using old migration table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I hit this route and perform the code below.

```
Post_Like::create([
      'like' => 1,
      'post_id' => 1,
      'user_id' => 2,
]);
```

The error below occurs.

**Table 'database.post__likes' doesn't exist**

Here is my migration file. Before I misspelled the table name. I typed post__likes when it was suppose to be post_likes. So I deleted that migration file and made a new one. Now I typed post_likes. But now it keeps saying the post__likes table does not exist. It's suppose to be using post_likes not post__likes.

**Old Migration File: 2018_03_03_114895_create_post__likes_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostLikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post__likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->boolean('like');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post__likes');
    }
}
```

**New Migration File: 2018_03_03_248923_create_post_likes_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostLikesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->boolean('like');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post_likes');
    }
}
```

Post_Like model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post_Like extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['like', 'post_id'];

    // $post_like->post
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::Class); // App\Post
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your `Post_Like` model.

Comment: Try renoming your model to `PostLike` Laravel will add the underscore automatically when you use a camelcased Model. I guess when you named it "Post_Like" it added one more underscore since it detected the camel case.

Comment: Ok that works thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the table reference to your model like so:

```
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'post_likes';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting end of file

Answer (score 1):

Check your database,  migrations table, find and delete post__likes row.

Have to look something like this:
2018_03_4_000000_post__likes

Comment: I tried that. I deleted everything in the migrations table and all my tables. I wiped my entire database and then did php artisan migrate. But it keeps  saying "Table 'database.post__likes' doesn't exist".

Answer (score 1):

I hope you may have solved the problem as @Paras pointed it out for you. I want to be in a little detail though.

Laravel follows simple naming convention. Table name should be plural to the model name. And for models which contain multiple words, like Post_Like the naming convention is to use CamelCase not snake_case so the proper naming would have been PostLike so the migration generated will be what laravel was expecting post_like. When you create snake_case models you have to create migration with double underscore between words like post__likes and in case you want to override the naming convention you simply needs to make use of the properties on the model $table.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post_Like extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['like', 'post_id'];
    protected $table = "post__likes";

    // $post_like->post
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::Class); // App\Post
    }

}
```